SmartSheet is bypassing the proxy
Here is my code
var client = new SmartsheetBuilder()
.SetHttpClient(new ProxyHttpClient("https://www.example.com", 100, _logger))
.SetAccessToken(page.Token)
.Build();

var sheet = client.SheetResources.GetSheet(page.PageId.Value, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);


public class ProxyHttpClient: DefaultHttpClient
{
    
    public ProxyHttpClient(string host, int port, ILogger _logger) : base()
    {
        if (port == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(host)) 
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"No Proxy");
            return;
        }
        _logger.LogInformation($"Proxy To {host}:{port}");
        RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(host, port)
            {
                 BypassProxyOnLocal = false
            },
            BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets"),
        };
        httpClient = new RestClient(options);
        
        
    }
}

When I use this could the var sheet = client.SheetResources.GetSheet works even though there is no proxy at that address.
It appears to ignore the proxy.
I am following the example here
https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md

Are the two answers on this other post relevant/helpful to your situation?  >> Access SmartSheet API behind corporate firewall .Net C#
